# How to Sumif matching values different from X

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

This seems to be quite simple but I've been trying for a while without success.

I need the result of a `SUMIF` function but matching values different from `X`, like in the example below:

```
2    x
4    v
5    Y
6    X
```

If we sum the first column when the respective value of the second column is different from `X`, the result is `9`.

I have tried the following formula:

```
=sumif(B1:B4, NOT(X), A1:A4)
```

Also, I have tried the operator `^` instead of the function `NOT`, but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMIF(B1:B4, "<>X", A1:A4)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUM(FILTER(A:A, B:B<>"x"))
```

[image: 0]